# JPA and Business Logic - reuse same Criteria in both places

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, business-logic

We have an Entity, which contains additional (easy) logic for eg usage in the UI. The entity is the LegalForm and it contains two fields, which are queried in the Database as well as in the code, to retrieve, if the entity is of a specific type:

```
public class LegalForm {
  @Column
  private String type;
  @Column
  private String subType;

  public boolean isCorporation() {
    return type.equals("PLC") || 
           type.equals("FC") && (subType.equals("PLC") || 
                                 subType.equals("LTD"));
  }
}
```

The above snippet shows the method isCorporation, which is called in the UI to determine the type of the given Company, and is mainly used for a concrete, already loaded entity. We would like to determine all Corporations from the DB using the CriteriaBuilder, to find all corporations and use them for further processing.

Any hints on how we could leverage the same logic in CriteriaBuilder as shown in the Entity?

Obviously we could try to add these fields during import outselfes and later on query for those calculated fields. Any other way?

**UPDATE**

While the below answer of @Emre is totally correct, that is not what we wanted to reach. We would like to program the whole business logic only once and not reprogram the already implemented logic in HQL/SQL/CriteriaBuilder again. So basically me is asking on how to program the logic only once and reuse it in the Entity as well as in the CriteriaBuilder.

Should have made this more clear.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you are trying to generate query which equals to your isCorporation() method calculations.

Generated sql query :

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        legalform0_.id as id1_0_,
        legalform0_.subType as subType2_0_,
        legalform0_.type as type3_0_ 
    from
        LegalForm legalform0_ 
    where
        legalform0_.type=? 
        or legalform0_.type=? 
        and (
            legalform0_.subType in (
                ? , ?
            )
        )
```

Database has three rows as below:

```
select * from LegalForm;

+----+---------+------+
| id | subType | type |
+----+---------+------+
|  1 | XYZ     | PLC  |
|  2 | LTD     | ABC  |
|  3 | PLC     | FC   |
+----+---------+------+
```

Provided output of below code is :

```
LegalForm(id=1, type=PLC, subType=XYZ)
true
LegalForm(id=3, type=FC, subType=PLC)
true
```

Code :

```
package test;

import entity.LegalForm;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Expression;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        EntityManagerFactory emfactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Hibernate_Jpa");
        EntityManager em = emfactory.createEntityManager();

        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<LegalForm> cq = cb.createQuery(LegalForm.class);
        Root<LegalForm> legalForm = cq.from(LegalForm.class);

        Expression<String> subTypeExp = legalForm.get("subType");

        cq.where(
                cb.or(cb.equal(legalForm.get("type"), "PLC"),
                cb.and(cb.equal(legalForm.get("type"), "FC"), subTypeExp.in("PLC", "LTD"))));

        TypedQuery<LegalForm> q = em.createQuery(cq);
        List<LegalForm> allitems = q.getResultList();

        allitems.forEach(x-> {
            System.out.println(x);
            System.out.println(x.isCorporation());
        });
    }
}
```

LegalForm class:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class LegalForm {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column
    private String type;
    @Column
    private String subType;

    public boolean isCorporation() {
        return type.equals("PLC") ||
                type.equals("FC") && (subType.equals("PLC") || subType.equals("LTD"));
    }
}
```

persistence.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="Hibernate_Jpa" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

        <class>entity.LegalForm</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jpadb"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ddl-generation" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl" value="update"/>
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```